# HTML, Javascript : Sum values in div elements that have the same name and write sum into another div element

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the structure of the code. I commented the relevant tags. I essentially want to sum all product prices and then store the sum to display in the page via --> div class="totals-value"

```
        ... Several Products ....

        <div class="product">
            <div class="product-image">
                <img src="images/adidas.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="product-price">5.99</div>
            <div class="product-line-price">5.99</div> // I WANT TO SUM ALL OF THESE VALUES IN DOCUMENT
        </div>

        <div class="totals">
            <div class="totals-item">
                <label>Subtotal</label>
                <div class="totals-value" id="cart-subtotal"></div> // I WANT TO WRITE SUM HERE
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible using javascript or jquery
make sure you included jquery cdn or locally in your file before executing this code.

```
$(document).ready({
   let total_price = 0;
   $('.product-line-price').each(function() {
         total_price += parseFloat(this.innerHTML, 10)
   })
   $('#cart-subtotal').text(total_price);
});
```